# man pages broken after dist-upgrade

Tags: manpage

After a recent dist-upgrade, I have broken man pages. Symptoms are that `man <any command here>` refuses to load anything and shows a blank console, except for the line in the upper left:

```
Manual page man(1) line ?/? (END) (press h for help or q to quit)
```

After quitting, I get the following error line:

```
man: command exited with status 4: /usr/lib/man-db/zsoelim | /usr/lib/man-db/manconv -f UTF-8:ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//IGNORE | preconv -e UTF-8 | tbl | nroff -mandoc -rLL=195n -rLT=195n -Tutf8
```

This isn't helpful for me. I tried `sudo mandb` and `sudo mandb -c` with no success.

Comment: Does `sudo apt install --reinstall man` work?

Comment: No. I also tried purging, but it didn't help. Neither `man` nor `man-db` reinstall helped to get rid of the problem.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Possibly something relevant here? https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=889608

Comment: @steeldriver: This looks good. The first fix didn't help in my case, but I think that is exactly the issue here. There seems to be an issue with man 2.8.0 and higher - running man 2.8.1 here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following commands worked for me:

```
apt install apparmor-utils
aa-disable /usr/bin/man
```

Upstream Bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=889617

Comment: This apparently happens because the kernel is old.  Here's a thread: https://forum.pine64.org/showthread.php?tid=6453